# OpenTK 4: Is this how to set anisotropic filtering?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

In migrating to OpenTK4, I don't know if this is the correct way to set my `value` for anisotropic filtering.

Is it:

```
float value = 1.0f;  // Dummy value for example

GL.TexParameter(target, (TextureParameterName)0x84FE, value);
```

Is there an enum defined somewhere I can cast in its place? Instead of a hex code, that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anisotropic filtering  is part of the OpenGL 4.6 standard. See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 8.10 Texture Parameters](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=260&zoom=100,168,616).
However, the texture parameter TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_ (0x84FE, 34046) is missing in `enum TextureParameterName` (`namespace OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL4`).
In addition the parameter MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY (0x84FF, 34047) is missing in `enum GetPName`.

---

I have created an issue in the OpenTK GitHub repository:
[Texture parameter TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY is missing #1270](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/issues/1270)

The issue will be fixed in OpenTK 5. One workaround is to use `enum All` and cast it to the correct type:

```cs
float maxTextureMaxAnisotropy = GL.GetFloat((GetPName)All.MaxTextureMaxAnisotropy);
GL.TexParameter(target, (TextureParameterName)All.TextureMaxAnisotropy, maxTextureMaxAnisotropy);
```